# MySQL SELECT smallest row id with condition after an other condition is met

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL version table.
I'd like to get the smallest published version (published = 1) after the last changes (changed = 1).
The higher the version id, the more recent.

Here are some example of what i expect to be returned :

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | published | changed |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  4 |         1 |       0 |
|  3 |         1 |       0 |
|  2 |         1 |       0 |
|  1 |         1 |       1 |    <- I want this row
+----+-----------+---------+

+----+-----------+---------+
| id | published | changed |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  5 |         0 |       0 |
|  4 |         0 |       1 |
|  3 |         1 |       0 |
|  2 |         1 |       0 |    <- I want this row
|  1 |         0 |       1 |    
+----+-----------+---------+

+----+-----------+---------+
| id | published | changed |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  4 |         1 |       0 |
|  3 |         1 |       0 |
|  2 |         1 |       0 |
|  1 |         1 |       0 |     No rows should be returned
+----+-----------+---------+


+----+-----------+---------+
| id | published | changed |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  4 |         0 |       0 |
|  3 |         0 |       0 |
|  2 |         0 |       1 |
|  1 |         0 |       0 |      No rows should be returned
+----+-----------+---------+
```

What would be the more elegant way to handle this in MySQL (without having some external php logic) ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Question is not clear can you explain it better how and why the queries select that row and or nothing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Utilizing [Correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html), we can try to determine at-least one id (check the usage of `LIMIT 1`), which has `changed = 1`, and is less than or equal to the row id.
- We consider only those rows which have `published = 1`.
- Filter out those rows, which have earlier changed id(s) using `EXISTS`.
- Using `ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1`, we limit our final result set to minimum id.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.published, 
       t1.changed 
FROM your_table AS t1 
WHERE t1.published = 1 
  AND EXISTS ( 
               SELECT t2.id 
               FROM your_table AS t2 
               WHERE t2.id <= t1.id 
                 AND t2.changed = 1 
               LIMIT 1
             )
ORDER BY t1.id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```